# How to use markers in MatLAB

Tags: matlab, marker

I need to plot some results in Matlab. Using plot3 worked just fine, one problem did occur, though.

I use the following

```
plot3(x,y,z,'-rv')
```

How can I change the above code, so the markers appear on one, last, node only?

Any help would be much appreciated.

--

grnspn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot using two separate commands:

```
 plot3(x,y,z,'-r')
 hold on
 plot3(x(end),y(end),z(end),'rv')
```